# Disable URL rewrite for specific URL

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, index.php

I have the ShipStation extension installed in my Magento store (v2.4.4), and I'm having a problem with the APIs. ShipStation tries to connect at [www.mystore.com/index.php/api/auctane](http://www.mystore.com/index.php/api/auctane), but with with web server rewrites enabled, there is no index.php in the APIs URL. I tried the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/
RewriteRule (.*)index\.php/(.*) /$2 [L,R=307,NC,QSA]
```

It worked for configuration (POST), and it works for exporting orders (GET), but it won't work for shipment notifications which is also POST. It seems that it isn't redirecting. Is there a way to disable rewrites only for this specific URL?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, I simply can not get the request to work if I just rewrite the URL. It's something Magento is doing. Redirects work, but not with the shipment notifications. I solved it by rewriting the URL to an endpoint outside of Magento where I then used cURL to send it to the correct URL. I guess it's basically a proxy. I know it's a hacky solution, but it works.